# Discover meteor-Unsubscribe?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, meteor, publish-subscribe

I am currently working on my own project, based on the discover meteor book.

I have subscriptions of my collection 'posts'.

I am using easy-search (a search package), and currently having some troubles.

I have easy search on a overlay called in with javascript.

When I search, it will always return the posts included in the subscriptions + search result as the result.

For example, if I'm in the post lists page, if I search for Chocolate, the result would be every posts in the post list page + chocolate keyword posts.

It goes the same for single post pages.

I was wondering if I could unsubscribe temporarily with a click event. In this case, would be the search button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use [`Meteor.publish`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) for searching.

1. Create a [`Meteor.method`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) on the server instead to find the search results.
2. Create a client-only (unmanaged) collection [`var results = new Mongo.Collection(null)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)
3. When you perform the search, remove all results [`results.remove({})`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/remove) and then insert the results from the `Meteor.method` callback.

Then, to stop each search waiting until the next one completes (bad for autocomplete), you can look at calling the [`Meteor.method` with `wait: false`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_apply) eg.

```
Meteor.apply('mySearchMethod',[parameters], {wait: false}, function(err, res){});
```

To make this work, you need to call [`this.unblock()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_unblock) inside the search method.

---

Example Code

```
var searching = new ReactiveVar(false);
var currentSearch = "";
var results = new Mongo.Collection(null);
var search = function(searchText){
  searchText = searchText.trim();
  if (searchText === currentSearch){
     // abort search if query wasn't different
     return;
  }
  // clear results immediately (don't show expired results)
  // NOTE: this can cause "flicker" as results are removed / re added
  results.remove({});
  if (searchText === ""){
     return;
  } 
  searching.set(true);
  performSearch(searchText)
};
var performSearch = _.debounce(function(searchText){
  currentSearch = searchText;
  Meteor.apply('mySearchMethod', [searchText], {wait: false}, function(err, res){
    if (err){
        console.error(err);
    } 
    if (currentSearrch !== searchText){
       // query changed, results aren't relevant
       return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
       results.insert(res[i]);
    }
    searching.set(false);
  })
}, 300);

Template.myTemplate.events({
  'input #mySearchBox': function(e){
    search($(e.currentTarget).val());
  }
});

Template.myTemplate.heplers({
  'searchResults': function(){
     return results.find();
  },
  'showSpinner': function(){
     return searching.get();
  }
})


if (Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.methods({
    'mySearchMethod': function(searchText){
         check(searchText, String);
         this.unblock();
         var searchExp = new RegExp(RexExp.escape(searchText), 'i');
         return myCollection.find({myField: searchExp}).fetch();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just woke up and I feel like I got an early christmas present. I guess I'll have to create my own instead of using a package :)